# Icon over image on hover

Tags: html, css

How would I get the below href I icon checkmark over the main image when a user hovers over it. So when a user hovers over the image it appears in the top right corner of an image.

```
      <div>
        <img class="result-image" src="{{$property->photo}}">
        <!-- Encoding photo to add to url -->
        @php
          $codedUrl = urlencode($property->photo);
        @endphp

          <a href="/watchlist/{{$property->id}}/add?image_url={{$codedUrl}}&address={{$property->address}}&town={{$property->town}}&county={{$property->county}}">
            <div class="add-btn
              @if(in_array($property->id, $arrayInfo))
                active
              @endif">
              <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
          </a>
      </div>
```

This is my CSS.

```
.result-image {
  position: relative;
  background: no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
```

Comment: Well you'd have to make use of `margin` settings on the element in question, or `absolute` positioning. However, it's impossible to reproduce your problem given your above code. You'll need to update your question so that it takes PHP out of the equation, showcasing raw HTML and CSS in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the wrapper `div` position relative and `a` inside that div to position absolute. That's how you cna position icon over the image.

```css
.result-image {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}

.img-wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  float: left 
}

.img-wrapper a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  display: none;
}

.img-wrapper:hover a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js"></script>


 
 <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img class="result-image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="add-btn">
          <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```